# Preventing Android dialog from extending activities

Tags: java, android, dialog, extend

How can I prevent my dialogs from extending activities?

When I create it in my main activity it doesn't dismiss itself when I click "Okay", which creates a new activity. The new activity that is created extends from the MainActivity.

I am using shared preferences to determine where to send the user when they open the app. I'm not sure if that could be playing into this situation.

I want to prevent the dialogs from extending the MainActivity. It shouldn't be showing up on the other activities that I create.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("version", 0);
  int savedVersionCode = sharedPreferences.getInt("VersionCode", 0);
  int appVershionCode = 0;

  try { appVershionCode = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode; }
  catch (NameNotFoundException nnfe) { Log.w(TAG, "$ Exception because of appVershionCode : " + nnfe); }   

  if(savedVersionCode == appVershionCode){

      // Returning user
      Log.d(TAG, "$$ savedVersionCode == appVershionCode");

      // Temporary Navigation
      final Builder alertDialogBuilder = new Builder(this);
      new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getBaseContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Dialog));
      alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Temporary Navigation");
      alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Go to the new activity.");
      alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Okay", new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           Log.d(TAG, "$$ onClick");
              Intent newactivity = new Intent(MAINACTIVITY.this,NEWACTIVITY.class);
              startActivity(newactivity);
              dialog.cancel();
          }
      });
      alertDialogBuilder.show();
      // End

  } else {

      // First time visitor
      Log.d(TAG, "$$ savedVersionCode != appVershionCode");

      // Hide graphics meant for returning users
      ((Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

      SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
      sharedPreferencesEditor.putInt("VersionCode", appVershionCode);
      sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();

      Builder alertDialogBuilder = new Builder(this);
      alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Welcome");
      alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Click Okay to continue.");

      alertDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton("Okay", new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           Log.d(TAG, "$$ onClick");
              Intent leagues = new Intent(MAINACTIVITY.this,NEWACTIVITY.class);
              startActivity(leagues);
          }
      });

      alertDialogBuilder.show();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `dialog.dismiss()` like such:

```
@Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       Log.d(TAG, "$$ onClick");
          Intent newactivity = new Intent(MAINACTIVITY.this,NEWACTIVITY.class);
          startActivity(newactivity);
          dialog.dismiss();
      }
```

Comment: Thanks. That didn't work though. When I clicked the "Okay" button the new activity was created but the dialog carried over. Whenever I switch or create a new activity the dialog is triggered even if I didn't do anything to trigger it.

Comment: @PeterMerrill Have you tried to move these to say `onStart` or `onResume` just to see what happens?...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @TronicZomB. I did try that and nothing changed.

Comment: @PeterMerrill you're welcome. I'm not too sure then actually... Interesting problem though...

Answer (score 0):

From a little understanding of your code, my suggestion would be keeping a check of when you want dialog to be shown and when you dont. e.g You can use a **static boolean flag showDialog**, set it true/false in your activity according to the use.

```
if(savedVersionCode == appVershionCode && showDialog)

if(savedVersionCode == appVershionCode && !showDialog)
```

Its more over over a programmatic problem with a programmatic solution. This is approach would be just a suggestion. As you are following a **singleTon** type of structure so you must be sure of methods you want to carry further.

Second approach could be, do not do it this way. The common method you want to implement in your activity is related to **SharedPref** checking, so why not :

1. Create a class which extends Activity.
2. Add your SharedPref related methods in it.
3. Now you can extend that class to all you activities.

   ```
   public class commonMethod extends Activity{

   public void my_sharedPrefMethod(){
   // do some thing with prefs
   }    

   @OverRide
   public void onCreate(){
   super.onCreate();
   // common onCreate code for every activity. Recommend not to change this
   // so that you can implement  
   }

   // you can also write other methods onPause(), onDestroy() here too.
   {
   ```

Now you can extend your classes with this class commonMethod. e.g

```
    public class main extends commonMethod{

    @overRide
    public void oncreate(){
    }

    @overRide
    public void my_sharedPrefMethod(){
    }

    public void showMyDialog(){
    // this way dialog box would not be shown on every activity but just this one.
    } 
    }
```

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example of how you would use your suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for that. Is there a way that you could use some of the code that I wrote in this example?